# Package manager for target file system

Tags: linux, package-management, dependencies, embedded-linux

I'm developing for an embedded linux application and I need to install some libraries that have a pretty lengthy list of dependencies. Is there a package manager out there that I can point to the target file system and specify the architecture? Or am I fundamentally missing a better way to go about this?

Comment: You are being too generic IMHO. More info on the embedded device are needed. Also, most Embedded devices do not have room for installing much: HW specifications could be relevant

Comment: This [hint](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/dpkg.txt) and this [one](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/rpm.txt) may help. Or, did you mean something else?